# How to clear Skype chat history?

Tags: skype

It seems that in the Window version of Skype, [there is an option to clear chat history](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/How-to-clear-chat-history/td-p/600991). It is supposed to be `Tools > Options > IM & SMS > Clear history button` but effectively nothing similar is here:

[image: No clear history button]

This option is not present on the version that come with my Ubuntu 13.04. In the privacy settings there is this option:

[image]

and somewhere in the Skype forum it is said that changing that to Disable History and then restarting Skype will get rid of the chat history. Tried that, don't work.

Searching a bit I found that you have to [eliminate some file in the Skype directory](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-delete-skype-chat-call-history-in-fedora-806970/); I did that from the directory I have:

```
cd $HOME/.Skype/my_skype_name/ 
rm chat*.dbb user*.dbb
```

...still no go. Before I get rid of all the .Skype directory and re-configure all Skype, is there anyone that know how to do it? The content of the directory is:

```
alert2048.dbb       chatsync             httpfe           msn.db-journal
alert4096.dbb       config.lck           keyval.db        msn.lock
bistats.db          config.xml           keyval.lock      profile16384.dbb
bistats.db-journal  contactgroup256.dbb  main.db          sms512.dbb
bistats.lock        dc.db                main.db-journal  transfer256.dbb
call256.dbb         eas.db               main.lock        voicemail
callmember256.dbb   eas.db-journal       msn.db           voicemail256.dbb
```

Removing all other `*.dbb` doesn't work, either.

**Lesson**: never put sensitive data on a Skype chat.

Comment: Try this.  Click on Tools --> Options --> IM & SMS and the Clear history button.

Comment: @Mitch, that button is available in the widows and Mac version of Skepe, but not on Linux, as I say in the first paragraph of the question... What version are you checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm running Linux Mint 17, and was able to clear the chat history.  But you won't like the answer.

First I tried expunging all of the data in the ./Skype directory.  Didn't help, as everyone above has pointed out.

I have Windows XP installed in an Oracle VirtualBox VM.  I installed Skype in the VM Windows, then went to Options -> Privacy and set "Keep chat history for.." to Disable History.

Anyway, after deleting the old chats using the Windows installation, I went back to Linux Mint, started Skype, and guess what, folks?  --no chat history.

Comment: That really means that Skype is keeping that data online, and that does not provide Linux users with a way to delete it. Nice... Thanks anyway, +1.

Answer (score 9):

I was instructed by Skype customer service to do following:

1. Go to Options -> Privacy and set "Keep chat history for.." to Disable History, then sign out & sign in.
2. Go to $HOME/.Skype/my_skype_name/ and delete only main.db. Sign out & Sign in.

It worked.

Comment: Not sure why this was not the accepted answer. Works perfectly without a windows VM. However, it is strange that Skype team did not attempt to fix this glitch yet.

Comment: @KathiraveluPradeeban the problem is that in my case this thing avoided future recording of chat history, but *reloaded* the old one from the server. Besides, I do not want to disable chat history; I just want to forget the past one... to get rid of that password I typed in the wrong spot (blame click-to-focus...) ;-) (BTW, I ended changing that password...)

Comment: The solution above will in fact delete your history and recently contacted list.  WARNING: it will also delete all your contacts as well.

Comment: @BradHorn It never deleted my contacts. I tried it.

Comment: It hid all my contacts too. I managed to fix that by making a 'test call' through Options/Sound devices/Make a test call.

And it showed me that I did have a recent chat with one contact + I sent a file - that means it does not delete everything.

Answer (score 5):

How about nuke it? **WARNING** This will effectively nuke your Skype profile:

First, do a backup:

```
cp -r ~/.Skype ~/skype.bk
```

Now remove the .Skype directory:

```
rm -r ~/.Skype
```

Done.

Note that this will only remove the local copy of the history which will be restored by Skype on sign in.

Comment: Yep. Last resort weapon. ;-)

Comment: @Rmano wait, didn't we reach that stage already?

Comment: I've disabled the chat history in the options, quit Skype, removed the ~/.Skype directory. When I sign back in I can see all my contacts slowly getting reloaded from Internet and after a while all my conversations are reloaded as well. Using Skype 4.2.

Comment: @Krige if it's like that, then the history isn't locally stored.

Comment: @Braiam, that's what I guessed. So how do we get to clear the chat history in such cases?

Comment: @Krige that you should ask MS to do so.

Answer (score 1):

the terminal way of doing it, say the user’s skype username is ‘rome’ and the computer’s name is ‘russia’ :

```
rome@russia:~$ cd /home/rome/.Skype/rome/
rome@russia:~$ rm -rf `find . -name "*.dbb"
```

Comment: As you could read in the last paragraph in the question, I tried it. Doesn't work. It forgets very old chat content, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use skypeforlinux:

1- Quit the application.

2- Rename the file Databases.db inside this location:

```
~/.config/skypeforlinux/databases/
```

3- Restart skypeforlinux

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it on Skype 4.3.0.37 (because Mackys answer didn't work) was to delete all records from the table messages in the SQLite database of Skype.

First install `sqlite3` if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Then quit Skype to unlock the database and execute the following statement, changing the `[username]` with your skype name:

```
sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[username]/main.db "delete from messages;"
```

This will delete the chat history on your local computer, I'm not sure though if Skype will reload it from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete just one persons message. You need to do this. 
1 . Logout of skype. 
2. install sqlite3 (if it is not already installed)
    sudo apt-get install sqlite3 # installing sqlite3

3. then do this. (assuming that person's skype id is "nafis.ahmad")

   sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[your-skype-username]/main.db "delete from messages where dialog_partner='nafis.ahmad';"

Answer (score -1):

Found this, Helpful, I guess:
http://adminspot.net/topic/5042-removing-skype-chat-history-linux-ubuntu-should-work-for-other-distros-as-well/

Quote:
"Found this on the net thanks to the original poster

The current Linux version for skype 2.2 beta is lacking a delete history button
and there does not seem to be a bug ticket so, If you want to clear your chat
history.

With Skype not running open your home folder select show hidden files
find the one .skype rename it to .skypeold (or what ever).

Once you have logged back on skype you can delete the renamed folder

Bear "

Comment: yinon: this is EXACTLY Braiam answer.