# delete skype history from windows account does not delete history from ubuntu account

Tags: skype

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 version..

I would like to know where does the Skype chats are saved?

I  tried to delete  chat history from Skype using [How to clear Skype chat history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380489/how-to-clear-skype-chat-history?lq=1) and could not succeed.  I can delete Skype chat history from windows OS. So, i opened Skype account from some windows system and deleted there but even then i am getting chat history when i open from my system.

I would like to know why this is not working.

I have tried to do as said in answer below but it is not working..

I have deleted folders in chatsync folder and opened skype but it is not working... I have seen whether i have deleted that folders or not but then to my surprise all that i have deleted are still there.. I deleted them again and i saw again they are still there once i open skype... Now i did it again and folders came back again and history is still there..

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Ubuntu client already having logs saved to your disk. If you want to manually view the logs, then open your file browser to the home directory, then press `Ctrl+H` to show hidden folders. You should now see a folder named `.Skype`. From there, navigate to `.Skype/<username>/chatsync`. Now, you can manually clear the folder or whatever you had planned.

If you'd like to disable the client-side chat logs on Ubuntu, then open up Skype and select `Skype > Options > Privacy > Keep chat history for... > Disable History`

Comment: It is not working... i have deleted folders in chatsync folder and opened skype but it is not working... I have seen whether i have deleted that folders or not but then to my surprise all that i have deleted are still there.. I deleted them again and i saw again they are still there once i open skype...  Now i did it again and folders came back again and history is still there..