# Is ubuntu not good enough for skype?

Tags: skype

I just want to know if skype is not good enough for ubuntu..

When ever i am using other applications my system is responding properly but when ever i use skype it is getting stuck most of the times...
when i use video chat it cpu usage is going to 45%..  I am worried about this..

[delete skype history from windows account does not delete history from ubuntu account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617073/delete-skype-history-from-windows-account-does-not-delete-history-from-ubuntu-ac) is another reason why i thing ubuntu is not good enough for skype...

Is ubuntu not good enough for skype?

Do i have to make some changes in my system?

Comment: Did you go through [Skype Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting)? It says something about system hangs and other things.

Comment: I do not really understand what it is saying there @Ron..

Comment: Are you experiencing the same problem as in **System hangs for a short while (few seconds)** in that link?

Comment: @Ron Yes... I am facing same problem...

Comment: Then try the fix mentioned there.

Comment: That is what i am saying.. i do not understand what it is asking me to do... @Ron

Comment: Funny thing: Skype in GNU/Linux actually a bit better than the one in Windows®. I.e. context menu of the Skype icon in a tray have a line «Exit», so, in GNU/Linux it does exits the Skype, but in Win exits the… account!

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing the same problem as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SkypeTroubleshooting), follow the instructions given in the **System hangs for a short while (few seconds)** section. In summary:

Open your favorite text editor and copy the following codes in to it and save `skype.c`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int (* orig_pthread_create) (pthread_t *thread,
       const pthread_attr_t *attr,
       void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg) = NULL;

static void change_sched_policy (pthread_attr_t *attr) {

   int policy;

   if (attr == NULL) return;
   pthread_attr_getschedpolicy (attr, &policy);
   if (policy == SCHED_FIFO) {
      printf ("### SCHED_FIFO policy changed to SCHED_RR\n");
      pthread_attr_setschedpolicy (attr, SCHED_RR);
   }
}

int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread,
       const pthread_attr_t *attr,
       void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg) {

   pthread_attr_t new_attr;

   if (orig_pthread_create == NULL) {
      orig_pthread_create = dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_create");
   }

   change_sched_policy (attr);

   return orig_pthread_create (
      thread, attr, start_routine, arg
   );

}
```

In terminal type:

`gcc -shared -o libskype.so skype.c`

and launch skype as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to/libskype.so:/usr/lib/libqt-mt.so.3
/usr/bin/skype
```

Comment: where should i save that?

Comment: save `skype.c` wherever you like.

Comment: gcc: error: skype.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: run this command from the directory in which you saved `skype.c` or if you are running it from any other location provide the full path to the location of `skype.c` in the `gcc` command.